# Stock moves & multi-company

Tags: odoo

Structure: I created companies (A, B, C, D). B and C, D are children of A. Companies B,C,D has own warehouses. Company A don't have - it's main office.

I need to move some stock from B to C - I use internal moves. But products just go from one warehouse to another... And operation is visible only for manager from B.

What I want: Manager from company B start move some products to C. Manager from C see document about started operation, he approve it and only than manager from B can continue operation.

Is here an ability to do something like this?

The goal is to let managers from B & C to work together and see all documentation about moves from B to C.

The best way is to organise in OpenERP  something like internal sales. Example: Manager from C wants to get some goods from company B warehouse. Manager from B create sale order for company C. This SO and invoice created from it are visible in company C too. Than manager from B create delivery order (that is visible in C !) and than create stock moves

Has OpenERP something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

You Can select Destination Location and Source Location on Move line of Internal Move for movement of goods between two Child Companies.

Comment: so what should be the company of the move? Is it working for you